# What if I set session.gc_probability and session.gc_divisor to 1000 but not 1?

Tags: php, session

I read the definition of session.gc_divisor and session.gc_probability, both are using to calculate the run probability of garbage collection using method - gc_probability/gc_divisor .

I am using PHP 7.4.26, and default values were set to 1000 for both variable gc_divisor and gc_probability in php.ini. But I didn't understand what is the difference if we set 100 or 1 instead of 1000 for both variables.

2nd if we set 0 for both then what will happen?

Comment: Only the ratio matters, so you can use any absolute values you want. Using `gc_divisor=100` makes `gc_probability` a percentage.

Comment: The defaults are 1 and 100, not 1000 for each. You must be overriding the defaults in your `php.ini`.

Comment: The documentation doesn't say what happens when they're zero. Try it and see. But why do you care, why would you do that?

Comment: Thanks @Barmar for quick response, here is the comment written in php.ini for `gc_divisor` `; For high volume production servers, using a value of 1000 is a more efficient approach.
; Default Value: 100
; Development Value: 1000
; Production Value: 1000`

Comment: Since the values are integers, if you need a percentage smaller than 1%, you need to increase the divisor.

Comment: From a garbage collection running probability point of view if I set both values equal like 1 or 100 or 1000 then it would be 1/1 or 100/100. So, what does it mean "Garbage collection 'GC' process starts on each request?" and if we set it the same, is it cost intensive ? if yes, then cost intensive in terms of what?    AS YOU REPLIED IN LAST COMMENT ADDING ONE MORE QUERY >>> Lesser percentage is good or higher percentage is good ?

Comment: If they're equal then the probability is 100%, it will GC every time a session is started, which is cost intensive.

Comment: The point of that comment is that they don't want to GC very often. They set divisor=1000 so it only garbage collects 0.1% of the time instead of the default 1%.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, "for 100% it is cost intensive" but cost intensive in terms of what? what is consuming 'memory or something else ?'

Comment: In case it isn't clear, session garbage collection clears expired server data. For the default backend (files) that means opening the session directory, checking the last modification date for each file and deleting old files. That will use CPU and RAM (as any other computing process) and also involves disk I/O.

Comment: It's not usually considered very expensive, but doing it is more cost intensive than NOT doing. Doing it frequently will be a small expense every time, compared to doing bigger GCs less frequently. Determining the best option for your site will require benchmarking.